# Why is this mouseover jquery code not working?

Tags: jquery, html, function, onmouseover

I'm using the following code in the head area of the site (I've also tried the body):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function(){
    $("#h1").mouseover(function () {
    $("#h1").css("color","red");
  });
  });
  });
</script>
```

I'm also using this as the div (button):

```
<div class="button" id="h1"><strong>Home</strong></div>
```

Why isn't the font changing to red when I mouse over it? (Original color is white fyi)

Comment: When is your script executing? If you're not putting it in $(function(){...your handler functions here...}); and it executes before the DOM is constructed you could be attaching a listener to something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it still doesn't seem to work, I'm probably doing something wrong. I updated it above.

Comment: Correct answer. Once you wrap the script in $(document).ready(function () { }); this will work correctly.

Comment: I tried that also and its not working (updated) thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, in jQuery `this` always refers to the current element.  If you change `$("#h1").css("color", "red");` to `$(this).css("color", "red");` your code should be slightly faster since it already has a reference to the DOM element instead of having to look it up in its' internal cache.

Comment: The code in the current version of the question works.  You might have a CSS rule with `!important` that is overriding it perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time the inline script code runs, jQuery hasn't found any results to bind the mouseover to.

You need to wrap your inline script in a document.ready call like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#h1").mouseover(function () {
       $("#h1").css("color","red");
    });
});
```

[Ready about jQuery's ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap that inside of `document.ready`.  The issue is that you are attempting to attach a handler to an element prior to it being created.

You should read the doc for ready to get a better understanding:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/